# [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an error while logging a user to my application using facebook login.
I found similar question in previous answered question but when I apply I still have the same error.
The question was clear and [You can check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667941/auth-token-facebook-php-error).
Can anyone who had the same problem try to help me to add the exit statement as it was answered  in above told question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Facebook (PHP) SDK

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

> The Facebook SDK for PHP provides a rich set of server-side functionality for accessing Facebook’s server-side API calls. These include all of the features of the Graph API and FQL.

Comment: Thank you! When I use this I 've got more than what I expected

Answer (score 1):

It can only be said time and time again:

**Using the PHP SDK makes dealing with the API a lot easier, than doing things “manually” with file_get_contents.** So please consider using that instead, for your own benefit.

---

When file_get_contents used with HTTP URLs gets something other than a 2xx HTTP response code, it generates just a warning, and does not give you the HTTP response body, which in those cases usually contains the actual reason for the error.

To get this body and therefor the actual error message, you have to use file_get_contents with a `context` parameter with the HTTP context option `ignore_errors` set to true.

Comment: Thank you! When I use this I 've got more than what I expected.